# How to spread/distribute a number in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
id    rank    user
1      1       1
2      1       1
3      1       2
4      2       1
5      2       1
```

I would like to spread the `rank` value for a given user between 1 (or 0) and a max value to leave space between values. For example, I would like to spread the `rank` for user `1`, with max value of 100 (in this case), the result should be:

```
id    rank    user
1      20      1
2      40      1
3      1       2
4      60      1
5      80      1
```

I thought to calculate an `increment = maxValue / count(items) + 1` and then do many `UPDATE` queries using the `increment` for each new one, but that seems extremely inefficient. Is there a way to do it better, maybe with one big `UPDATE` query, something like:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET rank = increment * ??? (?current position? in SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE user = 1 ORDER BY rank)
WHERE user = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this result by using a `CTE` to generate a row number (`rn`) for each entry for a user (in order of `rank` with `id` to order duplicates) and also a count (`cnt`) of the number of rows for that user, and then set the `rank` for that user to be:

```
rn * 100 / (cnt + 1)
```

As a query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT id, user, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY rank, id) AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS cnt
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE "user" = 1
)
UPDATE MyTable
SET rank = CTE.rn * 100 / (CTE.cnt + 1)
FROM CTE
WHERE MyTable.id = CTE.id
```

Resultant table:

```
id  rank    user
1   20      1
2   40      1
3   1       2
4   60      1
5   80      1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc9b20/3)